# Can a class be created without a default constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

The following class is intended to "extend" Math.random, has no object properties and so needs no default constructor, yet one exists (by default).

```
public class Mathematics {
    public static long random( long lower, long upper ) {
        return (    
            Math.min( lower, upper ) + 
                ((long) (
                    ( 1.0 + 
                        (double) Math.abs( upper - lower )) * 
                            Math.random() ))
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have generic functions without having a default constructor?

Comment: I don't understand.  You are not using object oriented programming here--rather just creating a static method.  You don't need to instantiate a class and I don't see why a default constructor is necessary since you don't extend anything.  When you create a class that extends nothing, there is an implicit default constructor (an empty constructor that does nothing).

Comment: Also, I could be wrong, but I believe you _cannot_ override static methods.  This wouldn't make sense anyway since static methods should be accessed in a static way--i.e. you should use the class to call the static method _not_ a concrete object.  Therefore if you want to call this method you wouldn't call `Math.random()`, you would call `Mathematics.random()` so there is no inheritance.

Comment: My limited experience indicates that everything goes inside a class somewhere and so there's a default constructor. The default constructor in this class would create nothing, and so cause no real problems. I'm teaching myself Javadoc and the default always shows up if not dealt with and the intention is to NOT have a Mathematics constructor show up in the default Javadoc build.

Comment: Generally speaking you shouldn't create classes just to hold static methods.  Having said that, there are cases where this is appropriate (I think you gave one).  I wouldn't worry too much about the Javadoc.  If it's necessary to document it, then go ahead and create the empty constructor and I would state in the description that this is a collection of static methods and this class should not need to be instantiated (something to the affect of if you think you need to instantiate this class then you are probably using it incorrectly).

Comment: If you're truly determined to have no constructors, you can delete the `<init>` method with a bytecode transformer.  The verifier will not complain (if the constructor isn't called anywhere); `Class.newInstance` and other reflection will fail with NoSuchMethodException.

Answer (score 2):

A private constructor to override the default one will disallow instantiation.

```
public class Mathematics {
    private Mathematics() { }

    // Other stuff.
}
```

This is vulnerable to reflection (as in you can change the accessibility), but if someone is using reflection to instantiate a class of static methods...

As posted in the comments, if you're paranoid you can even throw an exception:

```
private Mathematics() thows IllegalAccessError {
    throw IllegalAccessError(Mathematics.class.getName())
}
```

Comment: To me this is hack (based on what I believe you want to do).  By declaring it private, the default setting will not display a javadoc description.  However, you can change the javadoc settings to display documentation for private fields/methods.  If the intention is to disallow the programmer from instantiating the class, then this is the proper way to ensure that.

Comment: And if you are a little paranoid, you can `throw IllegalAccessError(Mathematics.class.getName())` inside the private constructor, disallowing even reflective instantiations. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a private no-arg constructor, and it will be just as good as not having one.

```
public class Foo {

   private Foo() {}

}
```